# Encrypting/Decrypting Sensitive Data Across Pages

Tags: php, security, encryption

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, and I apologize in advance for the long question, but I am brand new to encryption and have Googled for days to little or no avail. I am using PHP with the Defuse encryption/decryption framework here: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

I would like to encrypt the data a user enters with a randomly-generated key in one PHP file using this framework and then be able to access the encrypted information and decrypt it later in another PHP file. I can use a session or store the encrypted data in a database, but my question is this: how should I securely store the key to decrypt the data when the user goes to access it again later? Correct me if I'm wrong figured that storing the key in a session or some sort of table would defeat the purpose of encryption.

For example, the file where the sensitive data is entered might look like this (excluding any error handling etc):

```
<?php

/* file1.php */

/* stuff to load in encryption framework */
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use \Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;
require_once 'autoload.php';

/* string to be encrypted */
$data = "Sensitive Data";

/* create a random key */
$key = Crypto::createNewRandomKey();

/* create the encrypted ciphertext */
$ciphertext = Crypto::encrypt($data, $key);

/* store the encrypted data somewhere (database, session, etc)
   with some sort of function I have made made */
storeEncryptedData($ciphertext);

?>
```

Then, the user returns to the site later on and needs access to the data:

```
<?php

/* file2.php */

/* stuff to load in encryption framework */
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use \Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;
require_once 'autoload.php';

/* retrieve the encrypted data from wherever I stored it earlier */
$encrypted = retrieveEncryptedData();

/* don't know where to go from here */

?>
```

So now that I have the encrypted data in file2, my understanding is that I would need to know the key that was generated in file1 to decrypt it. All of the examples that I have seen encrypt AND decrypt the data in the same file of code, meaning I need some way to securely get the key from file1 to file2. Is there any way of doing this without defeating the purpose of encrypting the data in the first place?

I should also mention in response to Isaac Raway's reply that I would prefer that the key not be stored on a client machine due to my inability to manage the client workstations that access this application.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow the user to download the key for safe keeping, as well as as store it in a cookie, and allow them to select the key file when they return in the event that the key is not in the cookie when they return due to an expired session.

In this way, the key is not stored on disk nor permanently in memory on the server, but is still sent with each request as a cookie header so that your code can do its encryption work. Note that this doesn't really qualify as zero knowledge because you are still sending the key back to the server, but it is much more secure than typical web apps would be.

For true zero knowledge, consider implement your encryption using a well tested JS library. You can still allow the user to copy the key for safe keeping and paste it back. Store the key using local storage instead of cookies in this case.

Also make sure that it is quite impossible to request anything on your site without SSL and set your cookies as secure only cookies. This is very important no matter what method you use.

Comment: First off, thanks for the quick reply. Nevertheless, I am looking primarily for a way to store a key on the server. I would give it to the client, but I have no control over the client machines and thus am trying to avoid a case where they give away the key to their encrypted data, if what I just said makes any sense at all :)

Comment: If you store the key and then encrypted content in the same place you defeat the purpose of encrypting in the first place.